# $S_4 \ne \langle (1,2,3,4), \, (1,3)\rangle$

Tags: abstract-algebra, permutations, symmetric-groups

So I'm trying to prove $S_4≠⟨(1,2,3,4),(1,3)⟩$, and I get the basic idea that $(1,2)$ swaps two things next to each other, which neither of the other operations do, and necessarily neither do their products. But I'm having a hard time formalizing this argument. Of course, the hard part is arguing that no product of these two could just swap neighbors. I know I could prove this by enumeration but that's boring.

Comment: Why did you delete your question and post a new question, instead of just correcting $S$ to $A$ with an edit?

Comment: What do you know about the group of symmetries of the square? (You may consider it as acting on the vertices of the square, which are labeled $1,2,3,4$ in clockwise order.)

Comment: You can show that $(1,2,3,4)$ and $(1,3)$ do not generate $S_4$ by showing that they belong to a certain proper subgroup of $S_4$, which has order $8$, and is in fact generated by those two permutations. You could just list the $8$ elements of the subgroup and write out the multiplication table, but if that's too boring, you can describe it as the symmetry group of the square. If you haven't seen those yet, look up ["dihedral group"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dihedral_group) in your textbook.

Comment: @bof I'm familiar with all of those, but it doesn't seem like a rigorous argument to say that this is like the dihedral group unless I exhibit an isomorphism, and I take it the isomorphism would have to be specified by the brute force that I'm trying to avoid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $g=(1\,2\,3\,4)$, and $h=(1\,3)$. So the order of $g$ is $4$ and the order of $h$ is $2$.

We have $gh=(1\,4)(2\,3)$, so $(gh)^2=e$. Rather, $ghg=h$. That means that any word consisting of $g^i$s ($0<i<4$) and $h^1$s can be reduced to not contain the subword $ghg$. If you have an $h$ surrounded by $g$'s on either side, you can reduce the $ghg$ to just $h$.

So there are not many words left to consider.

- No $h$ at all: $e, g, g^2, g^3,$
- One $h$ at the end of the word: $h, gh, g^2h, g^3h,$
- One $h$ at the beginning of the word: $hg, hg^2, hg^3$
- An $h$ at both beginning an end: $hgh, hg^2h, hg^3h$

Any longer word would necessarily have $ghg$, $h^2$, or $g^4$ as a subword. This is only $14$ words, and that is enough to reach your goal that this subgroup is not the entire $S_4$. (In fact, it only has $8$ elements, since there are duplicate representations here.)

---

Alternatively, if you have studied the dihedral groups, you might know that $\left\langle g,h\mid g^4=h^2=ghgh=e\right\rangle$ is a construction of the dihedral group of order $8$. So this group has order dividing $8$. Since it clearly has order greater than $4$, it actually has order $8$.

Answer (score 2):

Define a metric $d$ on $\{1,2,3,4\}$ as follows: $d(1,2)=d(2,3)=d(3,4)=d(4,1)=1$;
$d(1,3)=d(2,4)=\sqrt2;\ d(x,y)=d(y,x);\ d(x,x)=0.$

An **isometry** of the metric space $\{1,2,3,4\}$ is a bijection $f:\{1,2,3,4\}\to\{1,2,3,4\}$ which preserves distances, i.e., $d(f(x),f(y))=d(x,y)$ for all $x,y\in\{1,2,3,4\}$. Observe that the set of all isometries of $\{1,2,3,4\}$ is a subgroup, call it $D$, of the group $S_4$ of all permutations of $\{1,2,3,4\}$.

Observe that the permutations $(1,2,3,4)$ and $(1,3)$ are isometries. (Geometrically, viewing $1,2,3,4$ as vertices of a square, one is a $90^\circ$ rotation, the other is reflection in a diagonal.) In other words, $(1,2,3,4)$ and $(1,3)$ are elements of $D$. Inasmuch as $\langle(1,2,3,4),(1,3)\rangle$ is defined as the smallest subgroup of $S_4$ containing $(1,2,3,4)$ and $(1,3)$, it follows that $\langle(1,2,3,4),(1,3)\rangle\subseteq D.$

To finish the proof, all we have to show is that $D$ is a **proper** subgroup of $S_4$. For that, it suffices to observe that the permutation $(1,2)$ is not an isometry.

Answer (score 1):

Define $A = \langle (1\ 2\ 3\ 4)\rangle = \langle a\rangle$ and $B = \langle (1\ 3)\rangle = \langle b\rangle$.

Note that $A \cap B = \{e\}$.

Note as well that $ba = (1\ 3)(1\ 2\ 3\ 4) = (1\ 2)(3\ 4) = (1\ 4\ 3\ 2)(1\ 3) = a^{-1}b$.

This, in turn, implies that $ba^i = a^{-i}b$, so $BA \subseteq AB$.

Since $|AB| = |BA| = 8$, we conclude $AB$ is a subgroup of $S_4$ of order $8$.

Since $\langle a,b\rangle = \langle A,B\rangle = AB$ (since any subgroup of $S_4$ generated by $A$ and $B$ must contain $AB$ by closure), we conclude $a$ and $b$ do not generate $S_4$.